# How to solve 'No Matching Signature' error in chrome messaging API?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm making a simple chrome extension and I ran into this error. I've tried looking around to and the most I've found is that I'm likely running into an error with the parameters of the chrome.tabs.sendMessage. I tried console.log(tab[0].id) and it is in fact an integer. The docs say the message param can be a string and the other two params are optional and not needed in this context.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any 
message, optional object options, optional function callback): No matching signature.
at background.js:18:21
```

Here's my code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title": 'Help With PIM',
        "id": 'pimhelper',
        "contexts": ['all'],
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async (info) => {
    if (info.menuItemId === "pimhelper") {

        let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
        let tab = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage((tab[0].id, '"message"'))
    }
});
```

Possible ideas:

There might be something wrong with the message param and I read something about data serialization on the docs. Not sure how to use the JSON parse or stringify methods to solve this however.

I apologize if this is some noob mistake. I am entirely new to creating chrome extensions.

Comment: Deduplicate your parentheses: `((` to `(` and `))` to `)`.

Comment: Oof I should've taken a break before posting. Can't believe I overlooked that you're a savior!